# Menu Bar is Not Working properly

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

this is my home page image

[image: this is my home page image]

this my menu-bar that i cant able to click on it

[image: this my menu-bar that i cant able to click on it]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DccyE.png): [image]

This my menu-bar CSS code which i am using

```
ul.semiopaquemenu{ /* main menu UL */
text-align:center;
font: bold 14px Georgia;
width: 100%;
background-color:#99CCFF;
padding: 11px 0 8px 0; /* padding of the 4 sides of the menu */
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
<%--position:absolute;
height: 20px;
top: 114px;
left: 2px;
--%>      }

ul.semiopaquemenu li{
display: inline;
overflow:visible;
}

ul.semiopaquemenu li a{
color:Black;
padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px; /* padding of the 4 sides of each menu link */
margin-right: 15px; /* spacing between each menu link */
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.semiopaquemenu li a:hover, ul.semiopaquemenu li a.selected{
color: black;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); /* IE9+ SVG equivalent  of linear gradients */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.82) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 100%); /* fade from white (0.82 opacty) to 0.16 opacity */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.82)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.16)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.82) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.82) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.82) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.82) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d1ffffff', endColorstr='#29ffffff',GradientType=0 );
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #595959; /* CSS3 box shadows */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #595959;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #595959;
overflow:visible;
padding-top: 10px; /* large padding to get menu item to protrude upwards */
padding-bottom: 10px; /* large padding to get menu item to protrude downwards */
}
ul.semiopaquemenu li {
    position: relative;
    background-color:Transparent;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul.semiopaquemenu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    LEFT:-39PX;
    top:25px;
    background-color:#99CCFF;
    width:150px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:visible;
     background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 0px;
   <%-- border-left: 2px solid #4b6c9e; 
    border-right: 2px solid #4b6c9e; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4b6c9e;--%>
    text-decoration:italic;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
    ul.semiopaquemenu li ul a 
    {

    border-bottom: 2px dotted #F7F7F7;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:0px;
    display: block;
    overflow:visible;
   }

ul.semiopaquemenu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
       display: block;
    overflow: visible;

}
```

This is my Html Code

```
<tr>
                <td align="center">
                         <ul class="semiopaquemenu">
                         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                             </li>
&nbsp;<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbhome" runat="server" onclick="lbhome_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>

<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbFAQ" runat="server">Board</asp:LinkButton>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="MumbaiboardDepartments.aspx">Mumbai Board</a>
                 </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Kokan Board</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Pune Board</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbservice" runat ="server" onclick="lbservice_Click" >Service Search</asp:LinkButton></li>
&nbsp;
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbqs" runat ="server" onclick="lbqs_Click">Quick Search</asp:LinkButton></li>
&nbsp;
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbcr" runat ="server" onclick="lbcr_Click">CallRegister</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbcom" runat ="server" onclick="lbcom_Click">Complaint</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbrpt" runat ="server" onclick="lbrpt_Click">Report</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lblog" runat ="server" onclick="lblog_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton></li>
</li>
</ul>

                         </td>  </tr>
```

when i click on another page i cant able to click on sub menu bar.
please help me for this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KzK99/1/  is this what u needed??

Comment: why are you using table??

Comment: due to alignment problem

Comment: sir it is working f9 when its on in home page bt when i was in another page then i cant able to  use this menu bar

Comment: don't ever use table for alignment

Comment: cos i am facing problem regarding resolution problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KzK99/6/ check the fiddle it is working..!! Change the link button to <a> tag..! use div for alignment with css you can make wonders..!! Dont use table for alignment

Comment: not working please find Image Below

Comment: got it....! :) http://jsfiddle.net/KzK99/10/embedded/result/ :) i have updated the answer.. Check this fiddle add z-index:600; and position:relative to ul.semiopaquemenu{}

Comment: you want the sub menu to be placed above the post lottery portal right?? can you show me the code of post lottery portal div??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.semiopaquemenu { 
text-align:center;
font: bold 14px Georgia;
width: 100%;
background-color:#99CCFF;
padding: 11px 0 8px 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
height: 20px;
top: 114px;
left: 2px;
z-index:99999 ; /* using Z-INDEX */
position:relative;
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="semiopaquemenu">
    <li></li>
    <li> <a href="lbhome_Click">Home</a>

        <li><a href="#">Board</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li> <a href="MumbaiboardDepartments.aspx">Mumbai Board</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Kokan Board</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Pune Board</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="lbservice_Click">Service Search</a>

        </li>&nbsp;
        <li> <a href="lbqs_Click">Quick Search</a>

        </li>&nbsp;
        <li> <a href="lbcr_Click">CallRegister</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="lbcom_Click">Complaint</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="lbrpt_Click">Report</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="lblog_Click">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KzK99/8/embedded/result/)**

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

**change this CSS**

```
ul.semiopaquemenu {
    /* main menu UL */
    text-align:center;
    font: bold 14px Georgia;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#99CCFF;
    padding: 11px 0 8px 0;
    /* padding of the 4 sides of the menu */
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

    height: 20px;
    top: 114px;
    left: 2px;
   z-index:600px
        position:relative;

}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KzK99/10/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KzK99/10/embedded/result/)**